# Struggles with tidyverse and ridgeline plots

Tags: r, tidyverse, ridgeline-plot

I am a beginning programming student, & I am trying to formulate a ridgeline plot of temperature data, using tidyverse to group the temps by month.   The initial data looks like this:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to group the data by month using this code:

```
class(weather)  #what class is dataset = dataframe
head(weather)  #structure of the dataset  
attach(weather)  #attach column names
weather.month <- weather %>%
  mutate(month = weather$Day) %>%  #sort data by month
  group_by(month)
head(weather.month)  #view dataset with new month column
class(weather.month$month) #view class of column month = character
```

By this code, I get the image below:

```
ggplot(weather.month, aes(x = `High`, y = 'month', fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 3, rel_min_height = 0.01) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp. [F]", option = "C") +
  labs(title = 'Temperatures in Brookings in 2019')
```

[image]

I am trying to get an image like this:
[image]

I am assuming I am not grouping the data correctly, but I can't figure out how to fix it....any suggestions?

Comment: At the moment we have one `High` value for each group `month`. Could you please provide the full data?

Comment: Yes, I included a snip of the head of the original data.

Comment: In the future, you can use `dput(weather.month)` to create a more reproducible example.

Comment: I think you have a dataset with all 12 months of 2019? If this is true and your dataframe is called say `df` then do the following: In the console write: `dput(df)` then post the result.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the post to include the output from dput()

Comment: Screenshots of data aren’t usable for anyone wanting to reproduce your example. Delete those and provide the actual *text* output, so it can be copy-pasted.

Comment: Just replace `aes(x = 'High', y = 'month',` with `aes(x = High, y = month)` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, post the output of `dput(your.Data)` to help the community to help you. Furthermore, include the `library` you have loaded in your script, to let the people know where the functions you use came from. However, as suggested by @ mhovd you have to unquote the variable names. Since you don't post your data in a reproducible format I make an example with the built-in dataset `iris`:

```
library(ggridges)
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 3, rel_min_height = 0.01) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "mm", option = "C") +
  labs(title = 'Sepal Length')
```

wich give you:

[image]